# Lonny Bereal's "Don't Play with it", on YouTube and nowhere else?

Tags: identify-this-song, rap

I have found Lonny Bereal's song *Don't Play with It* on YouTube at this link:
 https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=7eOXEit4rEY

I used to listen to it as a kid, but I can't seem to find an official version, despite the A and B list stars that seem to perform in it. If anyone knows where I can get an official high quality version, that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This song has been released in the promotional mixtape by DJ Roc One [*R'n'B Generation Vol. 9*](https://www.discogs.com/DJ-Roc-One-RnB-Generation-Vol-9/release/10938426). The song is on the track #13 and the actual title is "Don't play wit it".

[image]

*"Where can I get" questions are off-topic, but in the album cover, you can have contact info.*